# How do have an angular-strap modal / aside trigger an event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I have a controller:

```
angular.module('mean').controller('LocationController', [
  '$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$aside', '$routeParams', '$filter',
  'ngTableParams', 'LocationService', 'UserService', 'CompanyService',
  function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $aside, $routeParams, $filter,
    ngTableParams, LocationService,  UserService, CompanyService) {
      $rootScope.menuItem = 'locations';
      $scope.contentTemplate = '/views/location/index.html';
      $scope.locations = [];
      $scope.current_location = null;
      $scope.newLocation = {};
      $scope.location_parent_id = $routeParams.location_parent_id;
      $scope.validation_errors = [];


      $scope.index = function() {
        CompanyService.initialized.then(function() {
          var company_id = CompanyService.getCompany()._id;
          LocationService.list(company_id, $routeParams.location_parent_id).then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.status === 'ok') {
              $scope.locations = response.data.locations;
              $scope.current_location = response.data.location || null;
            } else {
              alert('TBD');
            }
          });
        });

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
          page: 1,
          count: 10,
        }, {
          total: $scope.locations.length,
          getData: function($defer, params) {
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.locations, params.orderBy()) : $scope.locations;
            orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) : orderedData;

            $scope.locations = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

            params.total(orderedData.length);
            $defer.resolve($scope.locations);
          }
        });
      }

      $scope.addLocationModal = function() {
        $scope.location_types = ['warehouse', 'section', 'row', 'shelf', 'bin'];
        $aside({
          scope: $scope,
          template: '/views/location/addLocationAside.html',
          show: true
        });
      }

      $scope.createLocation = function() {
        $scope.newLocation.company_id = CompanyService.getCompany()._id;
        LocationService.create($scope.newLocation).then(function(response) {
          if(response.data.status === 'ok') {
            $scope.$hide();
            $scope.index();
          } else {
            $scope.validation_errors = response.data.error;
          }
        });
      }
  }
]);
```

In the modal, I have a form, that when submitted, calls `createLocation` function. If the location is created successfully, I want the modal to close and the index to run and re-update the list. But that doesn't seem to happen. I think it's a `$scope` issue, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: A fiddle would be great for this. Also where is this failing, is createLocation called? how about the promise callback? what is $scope.$hide?

Comment: It's actually not failing - it just doesn't redo the $scope.index() and update the items

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that it's not being called or it is? If it is, are all of the promises in that function resolving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more details, it's really hard to tell the problem. So here are some guesses:

**scope apply**

If `LocationService` doesn't handle `$scope.$apply`, you might need to call it in the callback inside `createLocation` for the changes to take effect. Example:

```
$scope.createLocation = function() {
    $scope.newLocation.company_id = CompanyService.getCompany()._id;
        LocationService.create($scope.newLocation).then(function(response) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                if (response.data.status === 'ok') {
                    $scope.$hide();
                    $scope.index();
                } else {
                    $scope.validation_errors = response.data.error;
                }
            });
        });
};
```

You may also need to to do that in your `$scope.index` method, inside the `LocationService.list` callback.

**initialized is only resolved once**

It's possible that the `CompanyService.initialized` promise is only resolved once, at the loading of the app, so you aren't actually updating `$scope.locations` after closing the modal. I'd change that to:

```
var isCountryServiceInitalized = false;

$scope.index = function() {
    function updateLocations() {
        var company_id = CompanyService.getCompany()._id;
        LocationService.list(company_id, $routeParams.location_parent_id).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.status === 'ok') {
                $scope.$apply(function () { // you don't need this if LocationService already calls $scope.$apply
                    $scope.locations = response.data.locations;
                    $scope.current_location = response.data.location || null;
                });
            } else {
                alert('TBD');
            }
        });
    }

    if (!isCountryServiceInitalized) { 
        CompanyService.initialized.then(function () {
            isCountryServiceInitalized = true;
            updateLocations();
        });
    } else {
        updateLocations();
    }

    ...
};
```

**ngTable reload**

It looks like you are using ng-table. You probably need to reload the table after updating `$scope.locations`. Use:

```
$scope.tableParams.reload();
```